# How to fill gaps between Text in C Language

Tags: c

I have a text and i want to fill it with data in C

```
char arr[100]="Ahmed %s salah %s is %d";
```

i want to add data instead of %s and %d 
    to be

```
arr="Ahmed Elsayed salah Elsenbawy is 16";
```

Comment: `snprintf` can do that.

Comment: To [the documentation!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). You'll need another buffer as a target. Hint: Use `char* text = "Ahmed..."` instead of a fixed-length buffer here.

Answer (score 3):

just use sprintf or snprintf.

Using char * causes buffer overflow in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    char arr[100]="Ahmed %s salah %s is %d";
    char temp[100];
    // fill the temp buffer
    sprintf(temp,arr, "Elsayed","Elsenbawy",16);
    //then copy 
    strncpy(arr,temp,100);
    printf("%s\n",  arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `snprintf` should be prefered (or `asprintf`) since it avoids buffer overflow